# MatInput value shows empty input fields after using value="x"

Tags: angular, angular-material

I tried to assign a value to matInput with this code:

```
<form [formGroup]="updateNoteForm">
   <input matInput formControlName="title" class="input-test" type="text" value="{{ note.title }}">
</form>
```

My component.ts:

```
updateNoteForm = new FormGroup({
    title: new FormControl(),
    content: new FormControl()
});
```

But for some reason is the input empty. Before I used a formGroup and matInput everything showed up perfectly. But as soon as I added FormGroup it just shows empty input fields.

Angular material docs do it like this:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Could someone help or is facing the same problem let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is provided by the FormControl. You need to set it like this:

```
updateNoteForm = new FormGroup({
    title: new FormControl(note.title),
    content: new FormControl()
});
```

Comment: Yes I know how that works but the problem is that I am assigning the value in a *ngFor="let note of notes". So how is it possible to do it in html?

Comment: Create a FormArray, which contains a FormGroup for each note.

Comment: Thanks I will try it